# Best way to MediaElement work in Background

Tags: c#, uwp

So I need MediaElement to work in Background. What's is the best way? 
I tried with BackgroundCapableMedia and is not working. I created a background task audio and I'm 99% sure I did everything right... 
So as I'm targeting Xbox One, I tried with the newer Background Media Playback, they said that you just enable on Manifest and it will magically work. Why is not working tho?
It just work with MediaPlayer APIs or MediaElement too?
I would appreciate if anyone could help me, thanks!

PS: In this case, I'm using MediaElement to play a video...

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

> In this case, I'm using MediaElement to play a video...

If I correctly understood your problem, you were trying to play video in the background? I am sorry to say, it is impossible in UWP app now.

The official document [Background Audio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/background-audio) will help you sort out the relationship between `MediaElement` in the foreground and `MediaPlayer` used in the background audio. For now playing video is not supported in the background, only playing audio is supported, you may submit a request to add this new features for developing through the Windows Feedback app.

Comment: I found a way using MediaPlayerElement (and the new Background Media Player Audio), there's just one problem: I can't get it to work with URI :/

Comment: interesting, can you please provide more details? thanks